# I'm trying to automatically use (nearly) the same text for the href="" and the <a> content </a> using css

Tags: css, attributes, href, element

I want to do either
<a href='#foo'>*[[generate foo automatically]]*</a>
or
<a href='#*[[generate foo automatically]]*'>foo</a>

I think I got that to work using CSS a few years ago but can not locate the trick now.

It might have been using xhtml??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can display content of attributes via CSS: You can use any attribute, not just data-attributes. You can't do any string manipulations like truncating the `#` from the rendered text tough.

```css
p::before {
  content: attr(data-test);
}

a::before {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<p data-test="Hello"> World </p>
<a href="#Hello"> World </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, can't use CSS.  Here is my solution using javascript:

...

```
    /*
     * scan all <a> tags for "href='#*var*'"></a>
     * and generate <a href='#*var*'>*var*</a>
     *
     * invoke via <body onload='fixHref()'>
     */
    function fixHref()
{
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (const element of elements)
    {
        let text = element.getAttribute('href');
        if (text.charAt(0) == '#')
        {
            text = text.substr(1, text.length-1);
            element.innerHTML = text;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}
  </script>
</head>
<body onload='fixHref()'>
```

...